# how to restrict user guest from accessing JMenuItem after log in?

Tags: java

guys,

I am new to java and i just want to ask something regarding user login. For example I have a log in form that can accepts two users, the guest and administrator. Is there a way that i can restrict guest from accessing some of the JMenuItem that the administrator can only permitted to use? Is there something to do with disabling the JMenuItem when the user log in is guest in enbaling all the JMenuItem if the user log in is administrator? Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JMenuItems can be disabled, and they can be added or removed from their menus based on program logic.  Are you asking someone to program it for you?  Questions here on SO are usually a little more specific.

Comment: actually i Already have a program the only problem is i really dont know the logic on how to implement this or where to begin with. Is this something to do with if statement? that if the user is guest disable some of JMenuItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any infinite number of ways this might be achieved depending on how you program is setup...

### You could

Use an `Action` for the menu items and simple disable them.  This could be achieved in a number of ways.

You could have a "Action Manager" which managers all the actions in the program, separated into areas (guest and admin).  Once the user logs in, you could simple enable/disable the guest actions as required...or have the "Action Manager" do it...

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details...

### You Could

Still using `Action`, you could set up some kind "Session" event which would notify interested parties that the user/session has changed.

The `Action`s could monitor these events and enable/disable themselves as they need to...

### You Could

Wait until the user logs and and simply decided what menu items need to be created based on the current user details...

This is nice, as the "user" never sees the "admin" menu items at all...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now i realize if what is the missing piece of my program.